# How to use git cherry pick continue

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have used Intellij to cherry pick a commit (by pressing `Alt 9`, then go to the `Log` tab and select the commit that I want to cherry pick and then click `cherry pick`), then it said there is a conflict. After resolving the conflict by editing the conflicted file in Intellij, then I run the following command in Git CMD,

```
git add *.java
git cherry-pick --continue
```

but then it shows up a black and white screen which list out the commit information and I'm not sure how to proceed with it. What is the proper way to resolve the conflict and what is this black and white screen?

Comment: Please see part 5 in section "Apply a commit to another branch":
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another.html#5c2bd554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "black and white screen" could be anything. Are you sure that's not just the editor allowing you to change the commit message? The default editor is `vim`. Type <kbd>:wq</kbd> (or <kbd>ZZ</kbd>) to write the file and exit; this will create the commit and update the commit message.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment now.
So this is a helpful [user guide link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another.html#cherry-pick) by Jetbrains.